# Unsupported Media Type 415

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, typescript, update

Estoy definiendo el metodo update pero al momento de
hacer el envio de los nuevos datos me retorna *PUT http://localhost:8080/proyecto_ap/elemento/undefined 415 OK Unsupported Media Type*. Los demas metodos funcionan perfecto. Entiendo que puede ser un error de comunicacion, revise el backend y todo esta correcto asi que el error se genera en el front. Si alguien me podria orientar estaria muy agradecido, soy nuevo en este mundo y realmente quiero mejorar! Muchas gracias!

**Este es el componente del form para actualizar**

```js
import { expe } from './../../model/expe';
import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth.service';
import { PorfolioService } from 'src/app/services/porfolio.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lexpe',
  templateUrl: './lexpe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lexpe.component.css']
})
export class LexpeComponent implements OnInit {

  exper:expe = new expe();
  experiencia: expe[];

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router, private service: PorfolioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.service.getExpe()
    .subscribe(data =>{
      this.experiencia=data;
    });

  }

  EditarExpe(exper:expe): void{
    localStorage.setItem("id", exper.id?.toString());
    this.router.navigate(["/Edit"]);
  }
```

**Este es componente de la tabla**

```css
import { expe } from './../../model/expe';
import { PorfolioService } from 'src/app/services/porfolio.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  exper:expe= new expe();

  constructor(private router:Router, private service:PorfolioService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Editar();
  }

  Editar(){
    let id=localStorage.getItem("id");
    this.service.getExpeId(+id)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.exper=data;
    })
  }

  Actualizar(exper:expe){
    this.service.updateExpe(exper)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.exper=data;
      alert("Se Actualizo con Exito!");
      this.router.navigate(["/Lexpe"]);
    })
  }

}
```

**Este es el servicio**

```html
import { edu } from './../model/edu';
import { expe } from './../model/expe';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  Urlexpe='http://localhost:8080/proyecto_ap/elemento';
  Urledu='http://localhost:8080/proyecto_ap/estudio';
  
  updateExpe(exper:expe){
    return this.http.put<expe>(this.Urlexpe + "/" + exper.id, expe);
  }

  getEduId(id:number){
    return this.http.get<edu>(this.Urledu + "/" + id);
  }
```

Aclaro tuve que agregar un **?** antes del *toString* ya que no me dejaba entrar al form dando el error *core.mjs:6494 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')*
Por lo que veo en los errores de la consola no me estaria tomando las peticiones PUT

Nose en que puedo estar fallando pero el CRUD me esta dando pelea... y muy dura!